# Check uniqueness of a property in an enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I want to check whether some property is unique in an enumerable:

```
var Prop_is_unique = new[]{
  new{Prop="A"},
  new{Prop="B"}
};

var Prop_is_not_unique = new[]{
  new{Prop="A"},
  new{Prop="C"},
  new{Prop="B"},
  new{Prop="C"} // uh oh
};
```

Is there an elegant way to check uniqueness of a property with LINQ to objects? Something along the lines of:

```
Prop_is_unique.IsUnique(x => x.Prop); // returns true
Prop_is_not_unique.IsUnique(x => x.Prop); // returns false
```

Is there a simple and elegant solution with LINQ to objects or do I have to write my own extension method?

Comment: Not unique = If count of distinct is not equal to count of all.

Comment: Just realized that I can simply use `e.Select(x => x.Prop).ContainsDuplicates()` where `ContainsDuplicates()` has already been asked before.

Comment: @Sinatr nope, the answers in your dupe are less efficient, they need to enumerate the whole sequence even when a dupe is found

Comment: If I have to write my own extension method, I prefer to write a more performant one of course. See also, that I closed with a duplicate of myself ;-)